# Excel - VLOOKUP with two or more cells

Tags: excel, vlookup

I have next excel

[image]

I need in second table (green table) to add quantity from first table based on color and varinte. Can I use vlookup?

I need to get table like this:

```
red       Loc1     11
yellow    Loc2     45
```

Any idea?

Comment: you can use a `SUMIFS` formula

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your source range is in `A1:C6` and the lookup range is in `F1:H3` then you can use the following `SUMIFS` formula to achieve what you want - place it in cell `H1` and drag down

```
=SUMIFS(C2:C6,A2:A6,F2,B2:B6,G2)
```

Answer (score 0):

[image: Index and Match]

Index and match can accomplish this, you can see the formula in the image I've posted. Notice the curly brackets around the formula as well, this means it's an array formula, as opposed to a normal one (can be accomplished by pressing ctrl + shift + enter when you are done with your formula.)

Answer (score 0):

Vlookup with multiple criteria is easily achieved with the following workaround:

1. Make an additionanl column which unites the two columns, which you would like to vlookup on.
2. Vlookup on the additional column.

Sources:

https://exceljet.net/formula/vlookup-with-two-or-more-criteria

http://www.excel-university.com/vlookup-on-two-or-more-criteria-columns/